# Получение данных через related_name в django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Имеются две модели:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_comments')
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

Как мне в сериализаторе получить Post, но при этом, чтобы я в вывод мог добавить туда еще и комментарии.
Что-то типа так:

```json
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "title ": "Post Title",
            "text": "Post Text",
            "comments": [
                {
                   "post": 1,
                   "comment": "Comment text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно использовать [вложенные сериализаторы](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). Пример из документации:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

Вывод будет выглядеть так:

```
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ...
    ],
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Не знаете, как можно сделать, чтобы выводилось только последнее значение? К примеру у нас выводятся много постов и все посты имеют поле last_comment и выводился последний комментарий

Comment: прогоните этот самый последний коммент через сериализатор комментов. Вы должны понять, что сериализатору все равно какой и сколько комментариев вы ему отправите. Что отправите, то он и сериализует.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не понял( Не могли бы вы показать?

Comment: Допустим, вы написали сериазитор для модели комментариев и сериализатор для модели постов. Исходя из вашего описания, у вашей модели есть поле `last_comment`, которое ссылается на какой-то конкретный коммент, то есть значение в этом поле явлется экземпляром класса `Comment`. Значит, можно в сериализаторе для постов объявить поле `last_comment = CommentSerializer()`.

Comment: У меня в модели не поля last_comment. Я бы хотел вместо выводов всех комментариев к посту, вывести только последний

Comment: а, я вас понял. можно изначально во вью функции сделать итоговый кверисет, в котором у каждого поста будет подгружен только последний коммент. как например [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689019/18027287). Я уверен, что можно найти какой-то еще способ, но сейчас ничего в голову не приходит, так как я очень давно не писал на DRF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429368/18027287 - тоже неплохое решение вашей ситуации.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!